# Codepoint 985044 not found in font, aborting. Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, apk

when i am trying to make apk so getting error:
Codepoint 985044 not found in font, aborting.
And gradle build Fail.

Answer (score -1):

i had flutter version 3.0.2, issue found in this version.
just upgraded flutter version 3.0.5.
Issue resolved